# Python enumeration/row counter in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

New to the community with a Python (pandas/numpy) question.

I'm using pandas and numpy to create a sample dataframe for testing.  However, for several reasons, I need one of the colums to be an enumerator, or row counter, if you will.  I've tried the enumerate function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100
sample_data = pd.DataFrame({       
  'A': np.random.rand(N),
  'B': enumerate('A',1)})
```

but I keep getting this error:
    TypeError: object of type 'enumerate' has no len()

How do I go about doing this in the most efficient way possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Iterators, which enumerate returns, don't always support `len()`. `enumerate('A', start=1)` is basically the same as `iter([(1, 'A')])`, an iterable which will return only one value, because the string `'A'` has one item, which I'm not sure you want anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
N = 10
```

---

As a single step, you could use `range`:

```
sample_data = pd.DataFrame({       
        'A': np.random.rand(N), 
        'B' : range(1, N + 1)}
     )

print(sample_data)

          A   B
0  0.037303   1
1  0.693972   2
2  0.725926   3
3  0.110817   4
4  0.889411   5
5  0.138220   6
6  0.738190   7
7  0.695298   8
8  0.912171   9
9  0.601390  10
```

---

You *can* use `enumerate` as well, but you'll need to re-arrange the columns:

```
sample_data = pd.DataFrame(list(enumerate(np.random.rand(N), 1)),        
                     columns=['B', 'A'])[['A', 'B']]
print(sample_data)

          A   B
0  0.431247   1
1  0.004129   2
2  0.321802   3
3  0.866617   4
4  0.805049   5
5  0.767841   6
6  0.677050   7
7  0.293936   8
8  0.923059   9
9  0.953954  10
```

---

As an alternative, why not just use the index that the constructor automatically creates?

```
sample_data = pd.DataFrame({       
       'A': np.random.rand(N)})

sample_data['B'] = sample_data.index + 1
print(sample_data)

          A   B
0  0.117788   1
1  0.177268   2
2  0.762664   3
3  0.667486   4
4  0.531079   5
5  0.291939   6
6  0.066751   7
7  0.497935   8
8  0.883126   9
9  0.598048  10
```

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED.  However, I wanted to do this within the dataframe, as opposed to a separate step.

Comment: @Dsci Edited. Use `range`, not enumerate.

Comment: @COLDSPEED. Thank you. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Dsci As far as I can tell, this answers your question perfectly.  You attempted to use `enumerate`, COLDSPEED has recommended that you use `range` instead and has even demonstrated that it works as you've described.

Comment: @COLDSPEED.  Thanks again.  How do I add and define additional fields beyond the two in your example?  For example, if I wanted to add additional columns (C, D, E, and define them, how would I do that?  Many thanks again for your time and responses.

Comment: @piRSquared.  Thank you. However, I also need to define more fields in the data frame, and its not clear to me how to do that from COLDSPEED's excellent example.

Comment: @Dsci Ask a new question. This answers your current one.