# How to create a pandas dataframe with a random number column, enumeration column, and other string/integer fields?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is related to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965274/python-enumeration-row-counter-in-a-pandas-column), answered excellently by @COLDSPEED.

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns - a random number (A) and an enumeration column (B).

```
N = 100
sample_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=      ['A','B',],list(enumerate(np.random.rand(N), 1)))
```

However, I need to add other columns within the data frame within the data frame construct code and not a separate step.  These columns need to be a mix of string and integer, i.e., ANSWER=YES or C=1.

How would I do that within this example or another example?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question rephrased: how to add two more columns in the dataframe constructor? Okay, what does C contain? And what does D contain? Will there be more than C or D?

Comment: Let's say that C contains another random number generator similar to A, then column D contains a string (YES).  All the columns are unique in the dataframe constructor.